# MongoDB: Query, return documents that contain at least some of the Select fields

Tags: mongodb, select, find

Eg.
The collection:
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
{ a: 11, b: 12, c: 13 }
{ a: 111, b: 122 }

The query:
db.records.find( {}, {b, c} )

What I am trying to get here is something like this:
{ b: 2, c: 3 }
{ b: 12, c: 13 }
{ b: 122, c: null }

But I am getting only:
{ b: 2, c: 3 }
{ b: 12, c: 13 }

Is it possible to get what I want in a single query to Mongo?

Comment: in mongoDB, everything always has to be JSON(BSON) type
you shouldn't do '{b, c}' but '{b:1, c:1}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projections (second param in your `find` command) should be in this format: `{ b: 1, c: 1 }`

I get output similar to what you're looking for with this syntax:

```
> db.records.find( { }, { _id: 0, b: 1, c: 1 } )
{ "b" : 2, "c" : 3 }
{ "b" : 12, "c" : 13 }
{ "b" : 122 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, do you know how this would work for Mongoose use?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and the [$ifNull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator:

```
db.records.aggregate([{$project: { _id: 0, b: 1, c: {$ifNull: ["$c" , null ]} }}])
```

It is still worth explaining the general effects of `null`, as there is a difference between whether a key exists in a document or if it contains `null`. Consider the following query output:

```
> db.records.find({},{ _id: 0, b:1, c:1})
{ "b" : 2, "c" : 3 }
{ "b" : 12, "c" : 13 }
{ "b" : 122 }

> db.records.find({ c:{$exists: true}},{ _id: 0, b:1, c:1}) 
{ "b" : 2, "c" : 3 } 
{ "b" : 12, "c" : 13 }

> db.records.find({ c:{$exists: false}},{ _id: 0, b:1, c:1})
{ "b" : 122 }
>
```

This shows the query with a projection for only the b and c fields, so that is what is returned in the first instance. The third document is returned because we didn't limit we just projected. Using **$exists** as a query modifier this can be filtered either way as the c field does not exist in one of the documents.

Let's suppose we alter the third document and then look at the queries again:

```
> db.records.update({ _id: ObjectId("52ed85ecb87e33d680adb0fa") }, {$set: { c: false }})

> db.records.find({},{ _id: 0, b:1, c:1})
{ "b" : 2, "c" : 3 }
{ "b" : 12, "c" : 13 }
{ "b" : 122, "c" : false }

> db.records.find({ c:{$exists: true}},{ _id: 0, b:1, c:1}) 
{ "b" : 2, "c" : 3 }
{ "b" : 12, "c" : 13 }
{ "b" : 122, "c" : false }

> db.records.find({ c: true },{ _id: 0, b:1, c:1})
>

> db.records.find({ c: false },{ _id: 0, b:1, c:1})
{ "b" : 122, "c" : false }
>
```

So after setting a **false** value for c we can see the field in the results. It responds to the **exists** operator because it is there, and if the query is changed to filter results it will return as appropriate.

More information on the link:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-query-for-nulls

Comment: I forgot about $ifNull in the original response. The edit explains usage.